# Angularjs: How to get the value of modal and set it the current page

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and each row has a username and role input box. What I want to do is when the user click the open modal button in each row. The modal will show and he is able to choose what level of owner he like. For example he choose the `owner 1` and click the button `Get info`. The current page row will set the `owner 1` to `ng-model="row.role"` the `Admin` will become `owner 1 or 2 or 3.

My problem is I don't know how to passed the value of `getInfo to my ng-model`. Can someone help me how to figured this? Thanks

This is my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2968/

Sample code in my fiddle:

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.showModal = false;
$scope.toggleModal = function () {
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
};
$scope.users = [{
    'id': 1,
        'username': 'ady',
        'role': 'Admin'
}, {
    'id': 2,
        'username': 'tiu',
        'role': 'Admin'
}, {
    'id': 3,
        'username': 'ert',
        'role': 'Admin'
}];

$scope.setRole = [{
    'id': '1',
    'Owner': 'Owner 1'
}, {
    'id': '2',
    'Owner': 'Owner 2'
}, {
    'id':'3', 'Owner': 'Owner 3'
}];

$scope.getInfo = function(item){
    alert(item);

}
```

Comment: Where are you wanting to display the data that comes from the button he clicks?

Comment: I want to display it in the role input box.

Comment: So you just want the id and the Owner of the item to show up in the alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, First of all, add another variable to your controller

```
$scope.currentId=0;
```

Then change the open modal button click like this:

```
<td> <button ng-click="toggleModal(row.id)" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button></td>
```

Then `toggleModal` must change like this:

```
$scope.toggleModal = function (cid) {
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    $scope.currentId=cid;
};
```

And finally `getInfo` changes this way:

```
$scope.getInfo = function(item){
    alert(" id:"+item.id + "\r\n " + item.Owner);
    $scope.users[$scope.currentId-1].role=item.Owner;

}
```

Comment: I will check this one and I'll let u know if this one work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjs81sy2/
       ....

passed in the row selected in the ng-repeat, swapped out the values when click get info
     
         
             Open modal

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.showModal = false;
$scope.toggleModal = function (row) {
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    $scope.getInfo = function(item){
        row.role = item.Owner 
    }
};
$scope.users = [{
    'id': 1,
        'username':
   ...
```